# PHP Checkbox can not show checked on edit page

Tags: php, checkbox

There is a problem to show checked in checkbox on edit page.
There is my code below:

```
SSC<input type="checkbox"  name="ssc"class="form-control" value="SSC"

<?php if(isset($ssc)) echo ($data[6] == 'SSC') ? 'checked':''; ?>/>

HSC<input type="checkbox"  name="hsc" class="form-control" value="HSC"

<?php if(isset($hsc)) echo ($data[6] == 'HSC') ? 'checked':''; ?>/>
```

Comment: What you set inside `$ssc`, `$hsc` and `$data`? It's important because they cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, lets go throw the issues

- `mysql` functions were deprecated
- currently it is possible for an attacker can inject malicious SQL because the way you pass your variables
- beacuse your `$data` variable always contains the `education` column
- the value of a checkbox is sent only if it was checked otherwise it's not even set
- the `educatio` column can contain three value currently and none of them equals with your data

  - `SSC`
  - `SSC HSC`
  - `HSC`

Solutions:

- Use `mysqli` functions instead `mysql`
- Use prepared statements and parameterized queries.
- Don't check if a column is set if it is defined by your select query
- Always check if a checkbox value was sent with `isset` or add a hidden input with the same name and empty value above the checkbox so if the box is not checked the value of the hidden input will be sent
- check if the string contains those "words" (`strpos($a, 'SSC') !== false` - it's true when not false)

*(And do not use the answer section to give aditional data update your question instead)*

Answer (score 1):

Where did you assign $hsc/$ssc ? Why don't you make it like this :

```
if(isset($data[6]) && $data[6] == 'SSC') echo 'checked';
```

or

```
if(isset($data[6]) && $data[6] == 'HSC') echo 'checked';
```

for the other checkbox